# T - Flip Flop Using D Flip Flop (Verilog)

Tags: fpga, verilog, flipflop

I am trying to implement t flop  using d flip flop in veilog
for which my d flip flop code is like this :

```
module dff(D, CLK, RESET, Q, QOUT);
input D, CLK, RESET;    // Inputs to flip flop 
output Q, QOUT;     // Output of flip flops

reg Q, QOUT;            // Flip Flops need to store the previous value, therefore using reg

always @ (posedge CLK or posedge RESET) begin   // This block executes every time at rising edge of clk or reset
if(RESET)                           // If reset is high
begin
    Q <= 1'b0;
    QOUT <= 1'b1;
end
else
begin
      Q <= D;
     QOUT <= ~D;
    end
end

endmodule
```

And i am using this dff in my t flip flop module which looks like this

```
module tff(T, CLK, RESET, Q, QOUT);

input T, CLK, RESET;
output Q, QOUT;

wire out1;
wire out2;
assign out1 = T ^ out2;

dff uut(out1, CLK, RESET, Q, QOUT);

assign Q = out2;

endmodule
```

But on compiling the code i am getting an error which is 
**Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit tff on signal Q; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.**

Please help me where i am wrong in my code

Answer (score 2):

Q is assigned in two places.  Here:

```
dff uut(out1, CLK, RESET, Q, QOUT);
```

and here:

```
assign Q = out2;
```

Delete/comment out/change one or both of these.

Answer (score 0):

I think the Q argument of the dff instance should be renamed to out2.

Should look like this:

```
assign out1 = T ^ out2;

dff uut(out1, CLK, RESET, out2, QOUT);

assign Q = out2;
```